# Stuck downgrading libssl on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, downgrade

I have updated my `Ubtuntu 16.04` server earlier today, and one of my apps which uses `wkhtmltopdf` stopped working.

Based on the [thread here](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/3001), the solution is to downgrade and lock `libssl` to the previous version.

```
apt install libssl-dev=1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.8
```

When I try and downgrade:

```
vagrant@homestead:~/src$ sudo apt install libssl-dev=1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.8
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.8' for 'libssl-dev' was not found
```

Further info on my server is:

```
root@aubeta:/app# ldconfig -p |grep libssl
        libssl.so.1.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1
        libssl.so.1.0.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
        libssl.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so

root@aubeta:/app# apt-cache search libssl
libssl-dev - Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - development files
libssl-doc - Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - development documentation
libssl1.1 - Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - shared libraries
libssl1.0.0 - Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - shared libraries
```

I had followed the suggestion to try this version:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev=1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.10
```

With a similar result:

```
root@aubeta:/app# apt-get install libssl-dev=1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.10
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.10' for 'libssl-dev' was not found
```

Further screen outputs from commenters below:

```
root@aubeta:/app# apt-cache policy libssl-dev
libssl-dev:
  Installed: 1.1.0g-2.1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Candidate: 1.1.0g-2.1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Version table:
 *** 1.1.0g-2.1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status


root@aubeta:/app# sudo dpkg -s libssl-dev
Package: libssl-dev
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: libdevel
Installed-Size: 6961
Maintainer: Debian OpenSSL Team <pkg-openssl-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Multi-Arch: same
Source: openssl
Version: 1.1.0g-2.1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
Depends: libssl1.1 (= 1.1.0g-2.1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
Recommends: libssl-doc
Conflicts: libssl1.0-dev
Description: Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - development files
 This package is part of the OpenSSL project's implementation of the SSL
 and TLS cryptographic protocols for secure communication over the
 Internet.
 .
 It contains development libraries, header files, and manpages for libssl
 and libcrypto.
Homepage: https://www.openssl.org/
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The latest version of `libssl-dev` on 16.04 is `1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.10` (unless you are using an exotic architecture), so that is the one you should have. What does `apt-cache policy libssl-dev` say?

Comment: Are you by any chance running this on AWS EC2 instance or other cloud? Security issues are important so they might have their own flavour of OpenSSL. Check for example [AWS OpenSSL](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/openssl/). On that note, it might be beneficial to print what you have with `sudo dpkg -s libssl-dev`.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the replies. I have 2 AWS instances. I did `apt-get` updates on my beta (AWS) and my local (homestead). On both of these my app using`wkhtmltopdf` fails miserably. Upon research, I found this link (https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/3001) pointing to the `libssl` downgrade and lock. In contrast, my prod (AWS) is working perfectly since it did not get updated.

Comment: Hi @fkraiem I added the output of your suggested command.

Comment: Hi @DawidLaszuk  I added the output of your suggested command

Comment: Uh, why do you not have any official repositories enabled?

Comment: Oh, this is AWS... I really think AWS questions should be off-topic here, those systems are always so weird, they can hardly be considered official Ubuntu anymore.

Comment: yes but same issue with my Homestead image

Answer (score 1):

You should follow https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libssl-dev and download appropriate version and install using

> dpkg -i packagename

As you specified you are trying to get official version of libssl, Hope you can install from here. Below a image of different architecture are included.
[image]

Comment: It's unclear to me how to use this information.  I need to use 16.04.x for support and no permutation of commands can get `libssl-dev` installed. TIA

Comment: Visit this [URL] (https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libssl-dev) and download the deb file according to your arch and install the package using dpkg  -I package_name. 
I hope, It is clear to you.


Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't have standard Ubuntu installed, or at least build of `libssl` is not the official. You have `libssl-dev` in version `1.1.0g-2.1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1`, which name suggest to be a combination of `1.1.0g-2.1` OpenSSL build for `ubuntu16.04.1` with `deb.sury.org` (attempt `1`?).

You can see changelog for your release [here](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/+sourcepub/8478083/+listing-archive-extra). I think you can try to go with one of those versions (SSLv3 is disabled at `1.1.0~pre5-1`). Maybe try something before?

To make it clear, I don't think that downgrading SSL is the best idea both for  you and your clients. I think that the correct way would be to force `wkhtmltopdf` package maintainer to reflect newest protocol. This might not be feasible and fast, but it should happen.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with `wkhtmltopdf` and `libssl` has been fixed in the version 0.12.5 released on the 10th of June, 2018. Go to [the download page of wkhtmltopdf's site](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html) to download and install the update. So no need of downgrading `libssl`.