# How to use libssl-dev 1.0.1 on 19.04?

Tags: openssl, 19.04

Ubuntu 18.10 supported libssl-dev 1.0.1 family with standard Ubuntu PPA, but 19.04 seems to have dropped it in favor of 1.1.1. After the upgrade I can't set up my environment to compile project requiring this version of libssl.

How can I use an ancient version of libssl-dev on modern Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

Like this: https://askubuntu.com/a/989089/15811 That one is also about the dev  version. Mind that your system is likely to offer to delete a myriad of dependencies. Maybe you are better of installing virtualbox and 18.10 in that.

Basically the generic command for this is:

```
apt-get install {package}={version}
```

if in the repositories. If it is not you can download the package from the [packages website](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/libssl-dev) and also do

```
sudo dpkg -i {package}.deb
```

You will need to install the dependencies yourself (in this case the dependencies list is pretty short).

Again: be careful doing this and read all the notices and don't just enter yes on anything. This can wreck a system.

Comment: Thank you, this solution looks very sensible. I may or may not have done something wrong, but I've failed to baypas the problem with it, wrecked my system and will reinstall to 18.10, which should fix it completely.

Comment: Package is no longer in repository, nor is it available from the packages website link provided. (19.10)

Answer (score 1):

You can download the openssl tar.gz and compile the library (you'll also need to pass the installed location to the compilation of your project).

Something like this to install:

```
tar xvfz ~/Downloads/openssl-1.0.2s.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.0.2s
./config --prefix=/opt/openssl/1.0.2s
make
sudo make install
```

And then to build your project:

```
export CFLAGS=\ -I/opt/openssl/1.0.2s/include
export LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS -L/opt/openssl/1.0.2s/lib -lssl"
```